# Error: unknown command "chart" for "helm" on github actions

Tags: kubernetes-helm, github-actions

My CI deployments in github actions for helm/kubernetes have started failing with the following error:

`Error: unknown command "chart" for "helm" on github actions`

In my `CI.yaml` file, I have the following helm commands:

```
echo *****************
echo SAVING HELM CHART
echo *****************
# log in to aws and push the helm chart
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | helm registry login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXX.amazonaws.com
helm chart save ./server-helm-chart/ XXXXX.amazonaws.com/test/helm:$helmChartVersion
echo *****************
echo PUSHING HELM CHART
echo *****************
helm chart push XXXX.amazonaws.com/test/helm:$helmChartVersion
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Helm has removed the `chart` functions, so they are now replaced by `push` and `package`.

[image]

These changes are listed here:
https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.7.0

So I needed to rename my `Chart.yaml` to match the AWS registry name, and then my code became:

```
echo *****************
echo SAVING HELM CHART
echo *****************
# log in to aws and push the helm chart
# aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | helm registry login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXX.amazonaws.com
# export CHART_FILE=`helm package ./server-helm-chart/ | awk -F'[:]' '{gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2}'`
echo *****************
echo PUSHING HELM CHART
echo *****************
# helm push $CHART_FILE oci://XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging/helm:$helmChartVersion
```